# getting error in SonarLint configuration using Visual Studio

Tags: jvm, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

The following error occurs when trying to launch SonarQube:

```bash
C:\sonarqube-9.5.0.56709\bin\windows-x86-64>startsonar
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
jvm 1    | Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
jvm 1    | Unrecognized option: --add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
wrapper  | JVM Restarts disabled.  Shutting down.
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube 9 requires Java 11 to run, and later versions require Java 17. You can view the Supported Platforms in the documented prereq's here (select the version that is applicable to you): https://docs.sonarqube.org/9.6/requirements/prerequisites-and-overview/#supported-platforms

SonarQube will try and use the first java.exe it finds in the path, so if yours points to Java 8 or another unsupported version, then you'll see similar errors. To tell SonarQube to use a different installed Java version, set an env var `SONAR_JAVA_PATH` pointing to a compatible `java.exe` executable.
For example, say I have two installations `C:\java\openjdk-8\` and `C:\java\openjdk-17\`, with `JAVA_HOME=C:\java\openjdk-8\`. To point SonarQube to the correct Java version, I would set `SONAR_JAVA_PATH=C:\java\openjdk-17\bin\java.exe`. This is documented under [Setup and Upgrade -> Install the Server -> Adjusting the Java installation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/9.6/setup-and-upgrade/install-the-server/#installing-sonarqube-from-the-zip-file).